# Grails postgresql db connection

Tags: grails

Just started Grails. Went through all questions but still with the issue.
Connector seems in place.
[image: jdbc connector in the lib folder and dependency added to a class path]

repositories of BuildConfig

```
 repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
}
```

DataSource

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username = "postgres"
    password = "password"
}

environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/dev1base"
    }
}
```

And I get this:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.3-  1100.jdbc4 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.3-1100.jdbc4 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not find artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.3-1100.jdbc4 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

There shouldn't be magic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the formatting of your artifact. It should be:

```
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
```

Notice that the final period should be a dash instead.

Comment: You're right in 6 mins green check, but why it's not written somewhere clearly? grails.org/Quick+Start example shows this: dependencies {
        …
        runtime "postgresql:postgresql:8.3-603.jdbc3"
    }

Comment: @Maxim It would appear that postgresql uses different formatting with different versions. The more recent ones use a dash instead of a dot as well as an extra "org." prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dependency in `Config.groovy`:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
```

This is the version I am using, but you can try yours first (mind the format: add an 'org.' prefix and replace a '.' with a '-'). A even more recent version 1102 also seems to be available (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. *-jdbc4 in my case works too.